# How ignore a portion of the Vuex store in the Vue.js devtools

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-devtools

I'm working on a project that has a large data model and stores much of it in the Vuex store. This is manageable when working with fresh developer environments, but once our app acquires lots of data, such as in a QA environment, the Vue.js devtools crash as soon as I switch to the "Vuex" area of the Vue.js devtools and select a mutation to see the state at that time.

[image: Vue.js devtools crash]

Amending our data model or state management mechanism is not feasible in the short term, so I'm looking for a way to be able to inspect the Vuex store in mature development environments and QA environments.

In general, the portion of the store that grows over time is not usually the area of the store that needs to be inspected, so I'd like to be able to tell the Vue.js devtools to "ignore" or "exclude" that section of the store somehow. My thought is that if the Vue.js devtools aren't watching, parsing, storing, and recalling the troublesome area of the store, the crashes won't happen. Can this be done? How?

If there's no way to "ignore" portions of the store, are there tips, tricks, or settings that would help make the Vue.js devtools not crash when loading large stores?

Comment: Do I understand correctly you want just Vue Dev tools to ignore data but still keep it reactive in the app ?

Comment: in the top right corner you have a red circle button. this button can stop\start record each mutation and all of the state of that mutation. try to start record just before the mutation you need to inspect and stop it right after that. in that way you save only that mutation state and not use a lot of resource.

Comment: MichalLevý Yes, I want the app to remain completely reactive, and yes, I want the Vue.js devtools to record state information before and after each mutation,  but I only want the Vue.js devtools to store state information before and after each mutation for _portions of_ the store object, excluding uninteresting portions that are too large and cause the Vue.js devtools to crash.

Comment: @elichen Cool, that's a neat trick, but even if I only record one mutation, loading the state information for that one mutation crashes the Vue.js devtools, since the state is so large. Ideally, I'd record a portion of the state for all mutations that occur.

Comment: holding large info in vuex state is bad idea. its use a lot of memory and can crash or slow the app even without vue dev tool. the trick to get over it if you not need all the data in state to be reactive is use getter and some var to check the reactive system and hold the big data outside from state. i can send you example in the answer how to do that. btw check the memory tab in chrome how much mem you used

Comment: @elichen No disagreements here. Unfortunately, the current app design does rely on the large portion of the state being reactive, and it would be a significant refactor to attempt to change that particular part of the design. Fortunately, that large area is namespaced away from the rest of the store, hence the desire to "ignore" that portion when viewing mutation details.

Comment: a tricky way to debug without the dev tool is to bind the store to some window var. for example `window._store=store` and then put a breakpoint (or `debugger` statement) where you want to to check and then look in the console in the break time and check the `window._store`. i know its a tricky way.but for large data when dev tool cannot handle that can help